# Java Swing - Adding a row # column (row header) to a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have data from a database loaded into a JTable through a custom table model.  I want to have a column (should be the first column) which simply shows the **display** row number (i.e. it is not tied to any data (or sorting) but is simply the row number on the screen starting at 1).  These "row headers" should be grayed out like the row headers.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What TableModel are you using?

You can override `public Object getValueAt(int row, int column)` to do this in your TableModel.

I.e.

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    if(column == 1) {
        return row; 
    } ...
}
```

If that isn't working when you sort your JTable, then another solution is to implement it in a custom [`TableCellRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) and override:

```
Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                        Object value,
                                        boolean isSelected,
                                        boolean hasFocus,
                                        int row,
                                        int column)
```

Comment: Yes, I am extending AbstractTableModel. But I am not sure how to do this because the table can have an arbitrary number of rows, so I can't explicitly provide the row headers (i.e. '1', '2','3'...), I need it to automatically add the header

Comment: Oh yea, good call - I didn't think to treat it like a regular column.  Any idea how to get this column grayed out so that it stands apart from the "regular" table data?

Comment: @llm: Yes, you can change the color using a custom CellRenderer. Have a look at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Comment: Use a special TableCellRenderer on the first column to alter the appearance (border, color, fill, etc). Extend DefaultTableCellRenderer.

Answer (score 0):

This page might be what you're looking for: http://www.chka.de/swing/table/row-headers/JTable.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want a row header that remains fixed in place when you do a horizontal scroll (like in Excel), then you could merge two JTables together. This component shows you how its done :

http://blue-walrus.com/2014/12/row-number-column-in-jtable/